# Play a song Using Deezer SDK for Iphone

Tags: ios, audio, deezer

I’m integrating my application with the Deezer SDK, I already made the code so that I could authenticate myself now all I need my application to do is when I push a button a song starts how can I do this?

Is there any way to do it without having to click on the album artist and song? 
With a pre defined playlist or something?

Comment: Did you review the player section from the iOS documentation here: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/ios ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the play function on the PlayerFactory object whenever you'd like. The only you need to do before that is to configure the player with the preparePlayerForTrackWithDeezerId:stream:forUserWithToken:andId: method.

Comment: plz help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775236/is-it-possible-to-get-the-audio-stream-using-dezzer-sdk-and-process-raw-data-usi